# Apache FTPClient: What thread should/can "disconnect()" be run on?

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons-net

My Android app (min API 24, target API 27, Java 8) uses Apache's `FTPClient`.

All of the lengthy operations like login, download, upload,... run in `doInBackground` of an `AsyncTask` (it even throws an exception if you try to run it on the main thread) and the `BufferedReader`s,... are all closed in the according `finally` clause within.

`onPostExecute` returns error messages,... using a fake completion handler and currently it also takes care of disconnecting from the FTP server  by calling this code:

```
private void logout() {
    if(ftpClient!=null && ftpClient.isConnected()) {
        try {
            ftpClient.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //No point
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) but there's no mention of threading for `disconnect()` and it's not even always called from within `finally` there.

**Question:** Is `disconnect()` even able to stall like e.g. `connect()` (e.g. if you give it an invalid ip address) and is it okay to run this on the main thread (=`onPostExecute`)?

Comment: Do some tests and then tell us. And all network actions should be done in a thread.

Comment: How can I test this though? If you try to run e.g. `storeFileStream()` on the main thread, there's a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` but there's no exception for `disconnect()` and all the times I've run the code like that it never stalled. That doesn't mean that it's never going to though, that's why I asked this question.